# What kind of components are these?

Tags: components, inductor

[image: photo]

Parts is in red boxes. This is from a Chinese android TV box and I am searching for a replacement part. I searched around and it might be an a shielded SMD power inductor but not sure what to replace it with. I don't see any exposed coils on the side and I see 2 copper ends soldered on the board and no pins underneath it.

Comment: Those are almost certainly inductors. No idea what the value is though. The SOT23-6 IC's next to them are probably Switch-Mode regulators so if you can identify those then you might be able to look up some reference circuits to get an idea for what the inductors could be.

Comment: I wonder how you could determine they are broken and need to be replaced without knowing what they are and how to measure if they are still functioning.

Comment: @PlasmaHH. Good point. brhans may have best solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's a power inductor. Probably in the range of ~1uH.

You could get a hot air gun to heat it up, remove it and then measure the inductance.

This is the hot air gun I use: [https://www.amazon.com/WEP-858D-Soldering-Station-Suitable/dp/B0055B6NGE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055B6NGE)

...and LCR meters are a little more expensive than a regular multimeter, try Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/LCR-Meters/b?ie=UTF8&node=5011684011